# Hibernate DuplicateKeyException

Tags: spring, hibernate

I am developing a Spring Boot application, where I have a one-to-one relationship between the Trip class and the ApprovedTrip class. Additionally, there is a one-to-one relationship between ApprovedTrip and TripProductDescription. While managing data in the first two tables poses no issue, I encounter a Hibernate error when inserting data into the TripProductDescription table. The error indicates that the primary key I am trying to assign to TripProductDescription has already been assigned to ApprovedTrip. This is accurate, as both ApprovedTrip and TripProductDescription use the primary key of Trip as their own primary key.

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "trip")
public class Trip {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    //other properties and methods
}


@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "approved_trip")
public class ApprovedTrip {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @MapsId
    private Trip trip;

    //other properties and methods
}

@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "trip_product_description")
public class TripProductDescription {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false)
    private Integer id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "id", nullable = false)
    @MapsId
    private ApprovedTrip approvedTrip;

    //other properties and methods
}
```

When I call the method bellow I get the error

> org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: A different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session : [com.translogic.planner.model.ApprovedTrip#5]

```java
public TripProductDescriptionDto save(TripProductDescriptionDto tripProductDescriptionDto, Integer tripId) {
        ApprovedTripDto approvedTrip = approvedTripService.findById(tripId);
        if (approvedTrip == null) {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException();
        }

        TripProductDescription entity;
        if (null != tripProductDescriptionDto.getId()) {
            TripProductDescriptionDto data = findById(tripProductDescriptionDto.getId());
            entity = tripProductDescriptionMapper.toEntity(tripProductDescriptionDto);
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(data, entity);
        }
        else{
            entity = tripProductDescriptionMapper.toEntity(tripProductDescriptionDto);
            ApprovedTrip approveTripEntity = approvedTripMapper.toEntity(approvedTrip);
            entity.setApprovedTrip(approveTripEntity);
        }

        entity = repository.save(entity);
        return tripProductDescriptionMapper.toDto(entity);
    }
```

I also tried to merge instead to save, using the method bellow, but I got

> org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null identifier (com.translogic.planner.model.TripProductDescription)

```java
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager entityManager;

public TripProductDescriptionDto save(TripProductDescriptionDto tripProductDescriptionDto, Integer tripId) {
        ApprovedTripDto approvedTrip = approvedTripService.findById(tripId);
        if (approvedTrip == null) {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException();
        }

        TripProductDescription entity;
        if (null != tripProductDescriptionDto.getId()) {
            TripProductDescriptionDto data = findById(tripProductDescriptionDto.getId());
            entity = tripProductDescriptionMapper.toEntity(tripProductDescriptionDto);
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(data, entity);
        }
        else{
            entity = tripProductDescriptionMapper.toEntity(tripProductDescriptionDto);
            ApprovedTrip approveTripEntity = approvedTripMapper.toEntity(approvedTrip);
            entity.setApprovedTrip(approveTripEntity);
        }

        entity = entityManager.merge(entity);
        return tripProductDescriptionMapper.toDto(entity);
    }
```

So, I changed the method above to

```java
public TripProductDescriptionDto save(TripProductDescriptionDto tripProductDescriptionDto, Integer tripId) {
        ApprovedTripDto approvedTrip = approvedTripService.findById(tripId);
        if (approvedTrip == null) {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException();
        }

        TripProductDescription entity;
        if (null != tripProductDescriptionDto.getId()) {
            TripProductDescriptionDto data = findById(tripProductDescriptionDto.getId());
            entity = tripProductDescriptionMapper.toEntity(tripProductDescriptionDto);
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(data, entity);
        }
        else{
            entity = tripProductDescriptionMapper.toEntity(tripProductDescriptionDto);
            ApprovedTrip approveTripEntity = approvedTripMapper.toEntity(approvedTrip);
            entity.setApprovedTrip(approveTripEntity);
            entity.setId(approveTripEntity.getId()); //change
        }

        entity = entityManager.merge(entity);
        return tripProductDescriptionMapper.toDto(entity);
    }
```

but I still getting the error

> org.hibernate.AssertionFailure: null identifier (com.translogic.planner.model.TripProductDescription)

What can I do without change the model to save TripProductDescription?